# Factoring out a common term

Tags: expression-manipulation, factorization

Very simple question, but I can't find a simple answer here or in the documentation. I have an expression:

```
qq = a x + b x^2 + c x^3
```

and wish to factor out a defined variable/constant to get for example:

> ```
> qq = b (a/b x + x^2 + c/b x^3)
> ```

Bonus points for simplicity/readability.

Comment: `FactorByVariable[p_, c_] := c Expand[p/c]` where `p` is your polynomial, `c` is the variable you want to factor out.

Comment: haha... oh yeah.  Thanks !

Comment: @IPoiler. You should write-up your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Defining a function like

```
Clear[FactorByVariable]
FactorByVariable[p_,c_]:=c Expand[p/c]
```

will be one of the simpler options. The argument `p` is the polynomial you wish to factor from and `c` is the variable you wish to factor out.

I think the reason you can't get your desired result with something like `FactorTerms[a x + b x^2 + c x^3,{a,c,x}]` is because *Mathematica* doesn't know if `b` divides `a` and `c`; though, specifying `{a/b,c/b} \[Element] Integers` didn't seem to make `Simplify` want to factor the `b` out either.