# How to make FullSimplify always factor out terms?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Consider the following two `FullSimplify` examples:

```
a^2 q^2 + q^4 c^2 // FullSimplify
```

> q^2 (a^2 + c^2 q^2)

and

```
a^2 q^2 + q^4 (1 + c)^2 // FullSimplify
```

> a^2 q^2 + (1 + c)^2 q^4

I would like the output of the second example to factor out the `q^2` just like in the first example. Is there a way to make `FullSimplify` do that?

Note that the examples above are very simple just to illustrate the point. Ideally, I would like to apply the simplification to very large (rational) expressions that cannot be inspected visually.

Comment: Am I correct to assume that you don't want to use `Factor` for specific reasons? I am mentioning this because `a^2 q^2 + q^4 (1 + c)^2 // Factor` factors the desired `q^2` term.

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0 That's right, `Factor` is very limited. Even in this example, even though it factors out `q^2` it actually unfolds all other terms, which makes the expression less simplified overall.

Comment: Did you try using the `ExcludedForms` options of `FullSimplify`? For example if you consider `q^2` an excluded form that is not to be touched....

Comment: And another comment, in this particular example the following `a^2 q^2 + q^4 (1 + c)^2 // Factor // FullSimplify` gives the nice `q^2 (a^2 + (1 + c)^2 q^2)` which is of the form you're after. Not sure how much more complicated examples you want to consider.

Comment: Similar to [95993](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95993/factoring-out-a-common-term). Try: `q^2 Collect[expr2/q^2, q]` where `expr2 = a^2 q^2 + q^4 (1 + c)^2`.

Answer (score 7):

One way of doing this is to apply the following function:

```
factor[expr_, fact_, funExpr_ : Expand, funFact_ : Identity] := 
 Module[{a = fact, b = expr/fact},
  funFact[Evaluate[a]]*funExpr[Evaluate[b]]];
```

Here `expr` is the expression you intend to factor, `fact` is the term you intend to take out of parentheses. optionally you can apply a function `funExpr` to the expression left within the parentheses and the function `funFact` to the factor.
In the case of your example, the straightforward application yields

```
factor[a^2 q^2 + q^4 (1 + c)^2, q^2]

(*  q^2 (a^2 + q^2 + 2 c q^2 + c^2 q^2)   *)
```

However, if we need to have the content of the parentheses in the compact form we apply the function `Simplify` to the parentheses content:

```
factor[a^2 q^2 + q^4 (1 + c)^2, q^2, Simplify]

(*  q^2 (a^2 + (1 + c)^2 q^2)  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: That's an interesting approach! However, it narrows down the type of objects to very simple ones (polynomials) which one can inspect visually. Ideally, I am looking for a solution that would work on messy rational expressions that are hundreds of pages long and cannot be inspected visually, to reduce them to a readable output.

Comment: OK, have success in this hopeless matter.

Comment: I suspect that there is a certain tweak to the `FullSimplify` complexity function one can make to achieve this. It may be not as hopeless as it seems, but we for sure have to wait for someone who knows a lot about this stuff.

Comment: @Kagaratsch `ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + Total[Cases[#, _^x_Integer -> x, Infinity]] &)` works for your original example. The `Total[Cases[...]]` can be modified to favor more smaller powers or fewer larger powers as needed. Also, a scalar multiplier can be added to weigh it against the `LeafCount`.

Comment: @Kagaratsch By the way, in some cases, mapping of the functions like Factor, of Simplify onto expression may help. Like this: `Map[Factor, expr]`. It will try to take a common factor out of the parentheses in each term of your long-expression separately.  Also this: `Map[Simplify[Factor[#]]&, expr]` may sometimes occur useful.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 That works pretty well, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

In many cases, a simple solution is to apply `FullSimplify` to the factors of your expression, rather than the full expression itself.  This is very easily done:

```
FullSimplify /@ Factor[a^2 q^2 + q^4 (1 + c)^2]
(* q^2 (a^2 + (1 + c)^2 q^2) *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the approach given [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96029/106) by [IPoiler](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/30913/ipoiler)

```
q^2 FullSimplify[(a^2 q^2 + q^4 (1 + c)^2)/q^2]
```

$$ q^2\left(a^2+(c+1)^2q^2\right)$$

```
q^2 FullSimplify[(a^2 q^2 + q^4 c^2)/q^2]
```

$$q^2\left(a^2+c^2q^2\right)$$