# Factoring out a common term from a matrix

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions

This is a follow-up question to answer given by iPoiler on the original question, [`"Factoring out a common term"`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95993/9362). The function `FactorByVariable` works great for polynomials, but not for a matrix.
For example, I would like to factor out `1/Sqrt[2]` from the matrix `{{1/Sqrt[2]},{0},{0},{1/Sqrt[2]}}`. The function FactorByVariable went through the necessary steps. Howver, the last step simplify the intermediate step, `(1/Sqrt[2])Expand[{{1},{0},{0},{1}}]` to the original expression.
I started to study Quantum Computing. Factoring out a common term from a matrix (or tensor) is quite important. Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a link to the "original question"? Please edit the question and add it.

Comment: Does this help? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/70131/extract-common-factor-from-vector-or-matrix

Comment: Also related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/267910/factor-out-common-terms-from-a-list-of-terms

Answer (score 2):

You may extract the common factor in several ways. E.g. Using "Extract" if you know the position otr simply by replacing the common factor by 1.

However, the problem here is, if you have extracted the common factor, MMA will at once multiply it back and you are where you started. Therefore, you must wrap the simplified matrix into "HoldForm". However, this will prevent the extraction and you must force the extraction inside "HoldForm" by "Evaluate":

```
m = {{1/Sqrt[2]}, {0}, {0}, {1/Sqrt[2]}};
1/Sqrt[2] HoldForm[Evaluate[m /. 1/Sqrt[2] -> 1]]
```

[image]

This is not yet complete satisfactorily. You may also wrap 1/Sqrt[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wc8dt.png) with HoldForm:

```
HoldForm[1/Sqrt[2]] HoldForm[Evaluate[m /. 1/Sqrt[2] -> 1]]
```

[image]